# How to call a function right before leaving a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am kind of new to react and I am developing a Frontend for a REST-API.

My Frontend for a REST-API is organized in 5 Sites(Components) which are routed with `react-router-dom`.

Every time I enter a Site, the `ComponentDidLoad` dispatches an action, which in turn calls the API in my reducer.

```
export function getData(pURL, ...pParams){

    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get(pURL, {pParams})
        .then(result => {
            dispatch(getDataSuccess(result.data))
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(getDataFailure(error))
        })
    }
}
```

One of my Main sites looks as follows

```
class Overview extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getData(MyURLHere);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>

                {this.props.hasError ? "Error while pulling data from server " : ""}

                {/*  isLoading comes from Store. true = API-Call in Progress  */}
                {this.props.isLoading ? "Loading Data from server" : this.buildTable()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

let mapStateToProps = state => {
hasError: state.api.hasError,
isLoading: state.api.isLoading,
companies: state.api.fetched 
}

let mapDispatchToProps = {
//getData()
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Overview);
```

`state.api.fetched` is my store-variable I store data from every API-Call in.

`this.buildTable()` just maps over the data and creates a simple HTML-Table

My Problem is that I got the store-state variable `isLoading` set to `true`in my `initialState`.

But when I move to another site and then back to this one, it automatically grabs data from `state.api.fetched` and tries to `this.buildTable()` with it, because `isLoading` is not `true`. Which ends in a "is not a function" error, because there is still old, fetched data from another site in it.

My Solution would be to always call a function when leaving a component(site) that resets my store to it's `initialState`

```
const initialStateAPI = {
    isLoading: true
}
```

or directly set `isLoading` to true, in Order to avoid my site trying to use data from old fetches.

Is there a way to do so? 
I hope that I provided enough information, if not please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the function when leaving a component you can use `componentWillUnmount` function. Read more about React Lifecycle methods.

Comment: I tried to do so. Sadly this way seems to be too "slow", because when I call my `this.props.resetStore()` in `componentWillUnmount`, isLoading is still false when I reach the site. It only comes true when I already reached the `render()` of the next site..

Comment: Do you need to keep your `isLoading` flag in a redux store?

Comment: It would be a good idea to put the `isLoading` flag into the state. This way it could always be auto-true when entering the site.. 
But how would I modify this flag, then?

Comment: You can use Promises. For example: 
`componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getData(MyURLHere).then(() => this.setState({isLoading: false})
    }`
And your `getData` function: 
`export function getData(pURL, ...pParams){

    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.get(pURL, {pParams})
        .then(result => {
            dispatch(getDataSuccess(result.data))
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(getDataFailure(error))
        })
    }
}`

But when you configure your store you need to add middleware for example `redux-thunk`

Comment: It works! Just added the additional return to my action and the extra line at `componentDidMount`. I will try to understand how that actually works. Thank you really much!

Comment: One thing that still bothers me is that I now have to add a state called isLoading to every site-component of my Frontend.
Just a small question: Is this common practice? Or should I usually avoid stuff like that?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. But if this thing makes your sleep worse read more about HOC (Higher Order Components). This should do the job.